# Google Play shows - Your device isn't compatible with this version am not able to downloaded the application

Tags: android, google-play

we have uploaded a greeting appplication in play store. it working fine in mobiles. but in tablets i am getting the error as "this device is not compatible with this version". here is my android manifest permission. please check it and let me know if any one fine the mistake .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <!-- Permission to access network state - required -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to access internet - required -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Permission to use camera - required -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate - recommended, allows vibration feedback on scan -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- Camera features - recommended -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" >
    </uses-feature>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >

        <!-- Showing SplashScreen in Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




        <!-- Google map api key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have resloved this issues. i forget to declare  telephony permission require is false,

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" /> permission in my mainfest file, now am able to downloaded the app from google playstore.
```

thanks

Comment: More info about this [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#hardware-requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that you have to make it available for different screen densities and resolutions, you must make some screenshots for the tablet version, optimize layout for larger screens, use icons/assets designed for tablet screens, make sure you declare hardware dependencies (not all tablets have calling functionality or front camera). A full and detailed list is available in the official Android documentation http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html

Edit: for the beginning, upload a few screenshots made on a tablet, usually this is the 3rd option in the developer console which developers must complete [image: Developer Console Messages]

Comment: Someone would like to argument the -1?

Comment: Screenshots and optimized layouts are good things to do. They aren't why the Play Store is filtering the app.

Comment: Well, it appears they need also some screenshots for the tablet layout, beside the other tablet optimizations.