# Same Android version and same device model, but only one cannot download app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-security, google-play-developer-api

How is it possible that Galaxy s7 both with Android 6.0.1 behave differently in Play Store?

One I can download. Another will say "Your device isn't compatible with this version." This is also true for Galaxy s6 with Android 5.1.1.

This is not a once in a miracle occurrence. I have managed to reproduce both the downloading and failure to download in multiple Galaxy s7's and s6's. All in default Samsung roms.

How is this possible? Nowhere in Google's page says anything about how it can possibly filter the same device model with the same android version.

Update************************************************************

The devices that could not download the app were phones in the electronics stores, and they had CSC code of PAP, a CSC country code of HU, and no mobile operator. Googling tells me that PAP is used for Demo versions, which is obviously very likely the reason. Now, I need to find what in the demo version made it not be downloaded to confirm that it's specific to demo versions.

So, first I checked with region-specific publishing because it seemed like demo versions did not have a particular region. Turns out that two of my other apps that are set as global cannot be downloaded. I checked both my US google account and KR google account from my personal phone and both work fine with those apps. Even one another app that is set as Korea cannot be downloaded. Additionally, I was able to download one of my apps that is set as Korea only. Clearly, it seems unlikely it's related to region.

Comment: is your app is available region wise..?

Comment: Yes it is only available in Korea, but that's not the issue. I have already checked that other Korea-only apps can be downloaded when my app couldn't

Comment: Can you install the app on both devices via `adb`?

Comment: What is adb?? (word fill)

Answer (score 1):

What apps are you trying to install ? For Samsung phones, the same model (eg Galaxy S6, Galaxy Note 5...) can have different codes based on the regions that they are distributed. The developers can filter the devices based on the code so that, for example, the Galaxy S7 sold in South Korea cannot download the app but another Galaxy S7 for America can

Comment: It is not a region issue. Both sold in Korea, and already tested against another app that is korea-only. That app had no issue

Comment: Can you check the phone info using an app for example "Phone INFO Samsung" on the Play Store to see if they have exactly the same model ? Also, the Play Store can filter by carriers so it can also be a possible reason. [Phone INFO Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo)

Comment: I did that, and I will update that info in description

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using two devices with the same version, maybe the application is using a feature that one of them is not supported. Try to double check your inputs in the `<uses-feature>` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Also check if you properly use the correct SDK version.

Visit this SO question [22448645](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448645/google-play-shows-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-am-not-able-t?rq=1) and [10670002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670002/your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version) for more information.